# Text positioning in pictures created with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am sorry for previous problem, I am new on this useful forum and I still need help.

I have written the following code, in order to draw 2 coupled horizontal oscillators with dampers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
\tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}]
\tikzstyle{damper}=[thick,decoration={markings,
  mark connection node=dmp,
  mark=at position 0.5 with
  {
    \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=10pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-3pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,3pt)$);
  }
}, decorate]
\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.3cm]

\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
\node (M) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$m$} node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,below] {1};

\draw [<-,thick](-2.6,.6) -- (-1.5,-.2);

\node (wall) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=2cm,yshift=-3cm] {};

\draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);

\draw [spring] (wall.120) -- ($(M.north west)!(wall.120)!(M.south west)$) node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,above] {$k_1$};

\draw [damper] (wall.20) -- ($(M.north west)!(wall.20)!(M.south west)$) node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,below] {$d_1$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
\node (M1) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$m$} node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,below] {2};

\draw [spring] (M.10) -- ($(M1.north west)!(M.10)!(M1.south west)$) node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,above] {$K$};

\draw [damper] (M.-40) -- ($(M1.north west)!(M.-40)!(M1.south west)$);

\draw [->,thick](1.4,-.2) -- (2.5,.6);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
\node (wall1) [ground, rotate=90, minimum width=2cm,yshift=-3cm] {};

\draw (wall1.north west) -- (wall1.north east);

\draw [spring] (wall1.60) -- ($(M1.north east)!(wall1.60)!(M1.south east)$) node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,above] {$k_2$};

\draw [damper] (wall1.-160) -- ($(M1.north east)!(wall1.-160)!(M1.south east)$) node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,below] {$d_2$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I need help to fix the following issues:

1. The notations "d_1" and "d_2" of the two dampers should be placed with about 3mm, under the dampers.
2. The notations "1" and "2" of the two blocks should be placed under the rectangles and not at the interior.
3. The right-side point of the second damper should start from the vertical rule of the right wall, not from those north east lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points one and two are easily fixed as you can write `below=<distance>` and for point 3 you just need to draw the line from `(wall1.160)` instead of `(wall1.-160)`.

You can also rationalise your code a little by putting all of the style commands inside a `\tikzset{...}` at the top (see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)) and giving a name, I have used `blank` to the often used style `draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5`.

[image]

Here's the full code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.markings}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \begin{document}

    \tikzset{
      spring/.style={thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}},
      blank/.style={draw=none,fill=none,pos=0.5},
      ground/.style={fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.3cm},
      damper/.style={thick,
         decoration={markings, mark connection node=dmp,
           mark=at position 0.5 with
          {
            \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=10pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-3pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,3pt)$);
          }
          }, decorate
      }
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
      \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
        \node (M) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$m$} node[blank,below=0.7] {1};
        \draw [<-,thick](-2.6,.6) -- (-1.5,-.2);
        \node (wall) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=2cm,yshift=-3cm] {};
        \draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);
        \draw [spring] (wall.120) -- ($(M.north west)!(wall.120)!(M.south west)$) node[blank,above] {$k_1$};
    \draw [damper] (wall.20) -- ($(M.north west)!(wall.20)!(M.south west)$) node[blank,below=0.2] {$d_1$};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
    \node (M1) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$m$} node[blank,below=0.7] {2};
    \draw [spring] (M.10) -- ($(M1.north west)!(M.10)!(M1.south west)$) node[blank,above] {$K$};
    \draw [damper] (M.-40) -- ($(M1.north west)!(M.-40)!(M1.south west)$);
    \draw [->,thick](1.4,-.2) -- (2.5,.6);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
    \node[] (wall1) [ground, rotate=90, minimum width=2cm,yshift=-3cm] {};
    \draw (wall1.north west) -- (wall1.north east);
    \draw [spring] (wall1.60) -- ($(M1.north east)!(wall1.60)!(M1.south east)$) node[blank,above] {$k_2$};
    \draw [damper] (wall1.160) -- ($(M1.north east)!(wall1.-160)!(M1.south east)$) node[blank,below=0.2] {$d_2$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

`node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,below] {$d_2$};`

with

`node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,below,yshift=-2mm] {$d_2$};`

and this

`node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,below] {$d_1$};`

with

`node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,below,yshift=-2mm] {$d_1$};`

and this

`\draw [damper] (wall1.-160) -- ($(M1.north east)!(wall1.-160)!(M1.south east)$)`

with this

`\draw [damper] (wall1.160) -- ($(M1.north east)!(wall1.-160)!(M1.south east)$)`

Comment: I'm not Andrew but I hope the message conveyed :)

Comment: I am sorry, I've just seen Andrew. Thank you a lot, CroCo !